# How to feed bounding boxes in Regression head in CNN for object detection?

Tags: python, keras, object-detection, bounding-box

I am working on cropping the document Images from the center. I used pretrained model of VGG net and extract features from the images from the last convolutional layer.

I also get all possible bounding box from the image and also ground truth bounding boxes.

Here is the details:Total 25 Images(Demo purpose)

The Feature map size: (25,512,14,14)

All bounding boxes size: (25,) 
for ex. one image has 55167 bounding box , so (55167,4) (This is vary in some images)

True bounding boxes: (25,4)

Now How do I feed this in network ?

I also gone through some of the papers and resources. I don't want a classification layer , I only want box coordinates as a result.

I am using keras library.

Comment: If you want to detect where objects, are, you can probably go for a U-net or a Seg-net model. VGG won't locate the things it identifies.

Comment: @DanielMöller  want to crop the images, so probably once I got the bounding boxes , I can crop the images

Comment: Do you want your model to figure out what the boxes are? Or you just wants to preprocess your images before sending them to the model?

Comment: @DanielMöller No I want model should be predicted bounding boxes

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a localization network, not only classification. [This repository](https://github.com/endernewton/tf-faster-rcnn) supports also the 2 stages training to save you some training time.